# Isomorphic duality of two lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

If $\mathcal (X , T)$ is a topological space then the closed subsets as well as the open subsets form a lattice using $\subseteq$ as the partial order.
But I need to show that these two lattices are isomorphic dual to each other. 
What should I prove ? How to proceed.

Comment: Well, $A$ is open iff $A^c$ is closed, and $A \subset B$ iff $B^c \subset A^c$...

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But I need to know how to *formally* present the proof. Its more of the question that how to write the proof and more generally what are the requirements for Two lattices to be isomorphic dual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show duality between lattices $L$ and $M$, it suffices to exhibit a bijection $f:L\to M$ such that $$\forall l_{1},l_{2}\in L \, \left[l_{1}\leq l_{2} \iff f(l_{1})\geq f(l_{2})\right].$$

Comment: Thanks :) I guess it will be striaghtforward if I map each open set to its closed complement.